# How to compare two date groups?

Tags: sql, teradata

Beginner question here...

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT CAST(Date AS DATE)
  ,CITY
  ,CATEGORY
  ,COUNT(SALES)
FROM SALES_INFO
```

I need to compare two groups of data: Weekly sales that happened in the last 4 weeks (by week#) and another one that shows the daily sales of the current week (by day)

After getting the data, I would organize it like that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NisJS.png)

Can anyone please tell me what the SQL for that?

I tried to create two different date columns as well as using DateDiff to get the required date periods but getting error messages...

Comment: A [mcve] would make this much clearer. Note that most people here want sample data and expected result as properly formatted text (no images. no links.) Make it easy to assist you!

Comment: How is *current week* defined, based on 7 days up to today?

Comment: @dnoeth, thank you for your response. 
Ideally it would retrieve this week's data, eg. if today is 27-July, it would get from Monday 24-July to DATE-1. If it makes things too complex then last 7 days from DATE-1 will do.

Comment: @jarlh Thank you for the feedback. 
I would like to get the following results:

City         Category         Date1         Date1       ...         Day1             Day2   ...
London   aaa                  Week 26       Week 27           7/24/2023     7/25/2023

Comment: @NicoR, edit your question and add that info there, along with the sample table data. (People don't read all comments.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need *conditional aggregation* using CASE (untested):

```
SELECT 
  CITY
  ,CATEGORY
  ,COUNT(CASE WHEN DateCol BETWEEN NEXT_DAY(CURRENT_DATE, 'MON') - 5*7 AND NEXT_DAY(CURRENT_DATE, 'MON') - 4*7 - 1 THEN SALES END) AS "4 weeks ago"
  ,COUNT(CASE WHEN DateCol BETWEEN NEXT_DAY(CURRENT_DATE, 'MON') - 4*7 AND NEXT_DAY(CURRENT_DATE, 'MON') - 3*7 - 1 THEN SALES END) AS "3 weeks ago"
...
  ,COUNT(CASE WHEN DateCol = NEXT_DAY(CURRENT_DATE, 'MON') - 7 THEN SALES END) AS Monday
  ,COUNT(CASE WHEN DateCol = NEXT_DAY(CURRENT_DATE, 'MON') - 6 THEN SALES END) AS Tuesday
--
  ,COUNT(CASE WHEN DateCol = NEXT_DAY(CURRENT_DATE, 'MON') - 1 THEN SALES END) AS Sunday

FROM SALES_INFO
WHERE DateCol BETWEEN NEXT_DAY(CURRENT_DATE, 'MON') - 5*7 AND NEXT_DAY(CURRENT_DATE, 'MON') -1
GROUP BY 1,2
```

`next_day` returns the next weekday